# Capture errors/stack traces from jar in mac app bundle

Tags: java, macos

I have a simple jar application that works properly when double-clicked directly, but crashes when run as a `.app`.

The Mac console/system error application shows an `Exited with code 1` which means there's an error.

I tried adding the `WorkingDirectory` key/value to the plist as recommended by another stackoverflow question (cant find it again... hmm), however that didn't work.

I'm trying to find a way to capture the errors/stacktrace so I know what the actual problem is, and not just shooting in the dark.

**Update #1**

After much digging, I found a way to execute the java portion with some debugging:

```
$ export JAVA_LAUNCHER_VERBOSE
$ ./YourApp.app/Contents/MacOS/JavaApplicationStub
```

This allowed me to discover that the main class path was incorrect in my POM. Such a silly mistake.

However, while opening the application works with the above command, launching the `.app` with a double-click gives an error `-600`

Comment: Have you tried running it from Terminal.app? I mean `cd` into the `.app` directory and execute it.

Comment: I tried using `open` in terminal and still saw no output, the jar file itself executes without a problem when I execute/open it directly.

Comment: No, I don't mean with `open`. There is *something* inside the `.app` directory that you can execute directly from the terminal, if I remember correctly.

Comment: It's a java application that we're bundling as a mac .app, because the latest Mac OS X Gatekeeper won't allow "apple developer IDs" on a jar by itself. The jar always fine, outside the app, even when executed from the .app contents. It's only failing when the .app is the source executing the jar. I can't figure out why, and can't see any stack traces. The mac console app only shows some info on the filename, and "Exited with code 1". No stack track I can find, etc

Comment: This is all that shows in console: http://d.pr/i/NgXp

Comment: You were correct, there was a way to run the JavaApplicationStub instead. It helped resolve one issue, but now I have a new one...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, seems I've worked this out myself.

Doing the following allowed me to see the stack trace, which led me to the fact that my `<mainClass>` for mac app bundle plugin was incorrect.

```
$ export JAVA_LAUNCHER_VERBOSE
$ ./YourApp.app/Contents/MacOS/JavaApplicationStub
```

The eventual -600 error I was getting was cleared away by doing a `mvn clean` and `mvn package`.